# Error Installing Homebrew - Brew Command Not Found

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I've spent the bulk of my Friday trying to get the latest version of Ruby installed on my new MacBook Air (w/ Mountain Lion installed).

I have all the latest versions of XCode and command line tools. But I can't seem to get Homebrew to work! [Here's a screenshot of where I keep getting stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTU23.jpg) (I'm a new user, so can't embed this image).

As you can see I used the following to instal Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
```

While there was a "warning" it seemed as though the installation worked:

```
Warning: /usr/local/bin is not in your PATH.
==> Installation successful!
```

Despite that, when I try to run "brew doctor" I received the following:

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

Again, I'm trying to install homebrew, so i can instal the latest version of ruby -- I'm looking to learn to code in ruby, but kind of screwed if I can even get a development environment running! :)

Comment: I got this message running your line: Whoops, the Homebrew installer has moved! Please instead run:

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Also, please ask wherever you got this link from to update it to the above.
Thanks!

Comment: Operating Systems: Windows..I tried to install brew through $pip install brew
it went well downloading and unpacking. But my next task after unpacking brew is to install openssl using brew like $brew install openssl 
And I got an error stating brew command not found is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Homebrew on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381128/how-to-install-homebrew-on-os-x)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The warning is telling you what is wrong. The problem is that `brew` is kept in `/usr/local/bin`

So, you can try `/usr/local/bin/brew doctor`

To fix it permanently alter your bash profile (.bashrc or .profile in your home directory) and add the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

On Apple silicone it's

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: It worked super cool if we have ruby installed                                                 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"

Comment: Really helped :)

Comment: Future readers.  I did this (via a new .profile file in my ~ home directory).  But I also ran "source ~/.profile" (from a different answer I also upvoted) to make the changes "go live" instantly.

Comment: If you guys have macbook apple silicone, you should notice that path is different. You should use below path `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/:$PATH`

Comment: Had to put it in the file ~/.zshrc instead of ~/.profile in order for the command to be picked up (M1 Mac Mini here).

Answer (score 18):

Check XCode is installed or not.

```sh
gcc --version
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew doctor
brew update
```

http://techsharehub.blogspot.com/2013/08/brew-command-not-found.html "click here for exact instruction updates"

Answer (score 13):

```
nano ~/.profile
```

add these lines:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

save the file:

`Ctrl + X` then `Y` then `Enter`

then render the changes:

`source ~/.profile`

Answer (score 3):

This was just happening to me, but none of the suggestions above worked.  I changed directories ("cd ~/tmp") and suddenly the command

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

worked for me.  Prior to changing directories I had been in a directory that is a Git repository.  Perhaps that was interfering with the ruby and Git commands in the Brew install script.

Comment: changing to my tmp directory helped me resolve my related issue - which is that I was getting a message saying "Homebrew is already installed" - but none of the "brew" commands were working.  <br/>NOTE: the installer asked me to pass on the following message, so here it is everybody: ***"Whoops, the Homebrew installer has moved! Please instead run:  
<br/>
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"  
<br/>
Also, please ask wherever you got this link from to update it to the above.
Thanks!"***

Answer (score 2):

You can run in terminal

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"`

then install `https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh`.

When those complate run i.e pico editor `pico .zshrc` and past those lines:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

remember use `brew doctor` :)

[image]

Comment: This answer is now outdated. Throws error message:

The Linuxbrew GitHub repository has moved to https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew
Please see http://linuxbrew.sh for instructions to install Linuxbrew.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this:

```bash
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

to install homebrew.

Comment: the link couldn't be found you can use ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
instead