# Mac - Can’t install Homebrew

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I tried to install Homebrew like this:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

It didn’t install correctly so I closed Terminal and tried again. Now it displays me the following message:

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

I tried to do that but without success. The following message is displayed:

```
brew: command not found
```

So, the problem is that Homebrew is installed but actually it is not installed. Any suggestions how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I, too, had to download the tools .dmg separately from https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13.2/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_13.2.dmg, and install the tools. Reran homebrew install link with no problems after that.

Comment: This answer worked for me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268004/cant-install-homebrew). I have the M2 chip mac.

Answer (score 41):

This seems to have resolved the issue for me

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Afterward, I can now

```
brew doctor
```

You may also find the gist linked to at the following page of use:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md

Comment: Yes, your first line `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git` is the key for removing the broken partial installation! The installer link (your second line) however has been updated to `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score 9):

The URL contained in the command you are using is not correct. Ruby will dump out lines of HTML and then fail. Use this command instead:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`

Comment: For anyone reading this. you should use this command now instead:


ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)

Answer (score 6):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

this is work for me!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`

Answer (score 3):

I removed the folder `/usr/local/.git` and homebrew installed just fine afterwards.

Comment: I tried all the command line solutions elsewhere on this page, and for whatever reason they didn't work.  Finally I tried manually removing `usr/bin/.git` as suggested by AlexAffe, followed that up with `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`, and presto, I could reinstall Homebrew on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

What was the message given when it didn't install correctly the first time? Is the brew binary present in /usr/local/bin ? If so, you probably just need to add it to your path, see: [Error Installing Homebrew - Brew Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288682/error-installing-homebrew-brew-command-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to resolve the same issue, I found out that I had mistyped while making changes to my `PATH`. I did not have `/usr/local/bin`. I would then recommend running

> $ echo $PATH

in terminal to see if you have the correct directories.You can also run

> $ vi ~/.bash_profile

to see it and make changes if neccessary

Comment: Hi Wesley, and welcome to SO! I know you don't have the reputation yet, but just for reference, in future this probably belongs as a comment rather than an answer to the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot install by using curl try to open the install script from your browser, save it in a file called i.e brew_install.rb somewhere on your disk and run the script locally

```
ruby brew_install.rb
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow these steps 
1 ==> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"

2 ==> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/
      sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/Homebrew/

3 ==> install brew
      1 -- /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

      2 -- sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/homebrew

If get these error try below command
  Error: Failed to link all completions, docs and manpages:
        sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*

  then follow these commands
        /usr/local/bin/brew update --force
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most recent one that works for me.

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

I found it here in case it is updated later. https://brew.sh/