# Can't install homebrew

Tags: ruby, xcode, curl, terminal, homebrew

I have a fairly new macbook pro and I'm simply trying to install homebrew according to the directions on their site:

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

However, when I run this I get the following output:

`The user \u cannot be found
There was an unknown error.
This script requires the user \u to be an Administrator.`

My macbook only has 1 user, which is me, the Administrator.  That's who I'm logged in as on the computer.

Another thing I've tried is running the command with `sudo`, in which case I get the following message:

`Don't run this as root!`

Another thing I've tried is downloading `Command Line Tools (CLT) for Xcode: xcode-select --install` as I saw this suggested on Homebrew's site and elsewhere online.

After creating a new user with "Admin" privileges apart from my root account, the homebrew install command above started to run but then quit with the following error:

`/usr/local/homebrew/.git: Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q`

At this point I'm stuck and not sure what to do.

Comment: Changing the owner of /usr/local to your current user doesn't work? `sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local`

Comment: When I try running that as the root user, I get this message:  `chown: \u: illegal user name` and when I tried running that as the non-root admin user, I got a permission denied error: `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: I was able to get homebrew installed by following these instructions:
`cd /usr/local/Homebrew`,       
`git init`,      
`git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/brew`,   
`git fetch --all`,     
`git checkout -B master origin/master`,    
`cd /usr/local`,    
`ln -s /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew /usr/local/bin`, and note I did this on my non-root admin user account.  I'm not sure if it would've worked on my root admin account.  source: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5084#issuecomment-248834806

Comment: Great!, you can create the detailed answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks! Will do when it lets me (it says I have to wait for a day or something).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to install Homebrew using the following steps.  Note I did this on a non-root admin user account.  I had to create this user account separately and give it admin access just to do this.  Once I logged out of my root account and logged into the admin non-root account, I typed the following commands into terminal:

`xcode-select --install
cd /usr/local/Homebrew
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
git fetch --all
git checkout -B master origin/master
cd /usr/local
ln -s /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew /usr/local/bin`

I found most of these steps here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5084#issuecomment-248834806

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I was created as a standard user and could not run this command:  /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"      so I logged out, logged in using admin username and password and made my account admin, logged back in and reran the command, it worked.

Comment: Yeah, as long as you're not the root user admin and just a non-root user admin, that is what worked for me, though I wonder if things have changed since this was a while ago.

Comment: just for those who are a bit slow like me: make the directory `mkdir /usr/loca/Homebrew`, probably you will need to put `sudo` before it

Comment: first line says already installed, 2nd line says no such file or directory ?????

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Xcode first?

```
xcode-select --install
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then see if the installation was correct with "brew doctor"

Source: https://www.howtogeek.com/211541/homebrew-for-os-x-easily-installs-desktop-apps-and-terminal-utilities/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but yes, I tried that, and I get the same error message.  When I run the xcode command again it says "command line tools are already installed".

Comment: It seems that somehow you are not the admin of the system. You can try sudo su and then the ruby command to switch to root user before issuing the command or simply check that you are the admin in the system settings. It seems that Homebrew issued a warning in other versions: "set your user to be an Administrator in System Preferences or `su' to a non-root user with Administrator privileges". See: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-homebrew

Comment: When I open System Preferences and look under the "Users & Groups" menu item, it says the "Current User" is myself and it says "Admin" under that.  It's probable that I'm the "root" user, but I'm not sure how to switch to a non-root user or how to use "su".

Comment: I created another user with Admin privileges and logged out of my root account, then logged back in as this other user.  I was able to run the homebrew installation command, but it quit midway through with the below error:
/usr/local/homebrew/.git: Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q

Comment: Do you have git installed? run `git --version` whats the output?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall reinstall Homebrew.
Run `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local` and then reinstall