# Unable to install Homebrew in Mac OS Sierra

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew via the terminal, but can't get it to work at all. When I paste in the command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

as given on the Homebrew homepage, I get the following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

I can't connect directly in the browser either.  When I've Googled the error, I keep seeing solutions involving proxy servers, but I don't think that's my issue.

I tried downloading the tarball as given in the 'alternative installation options', and extracted it to /usr/local/bin, but it didn't seem to actually do anything. When I typed 'brew doctor', it didn't recognise brew as a command.

What can I try next?

Comment: For the tarball install to work (or any install for that matter) you need to add the bin path to your `$PATH`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14288750/735926

Comment: Thank you! I should have known that!